# Airflow Composer deleting specific xcom keys

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am orchestrating multiple dataflow jobs via Airflow in parallel. One of the task in pipeline execution is to push unique xcom key to store temporary value for each pipeline which is used to insert a value into Bigquery table. After the loading of data is done I have requirement to purge the specific xcom key . I do not want to delete other xcom key which may be generated by other dataflow job still running in parallel. Is their a way to purge specific xcom key?

Comment: Maybe you can push a new value for xcom after you finished with it. If you're using for password etc then consider switching to secretmanager instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the Airflow metastore DB from a task and delete the specific `XCom` you want to remove.  There isn't an existing method to perform specific `XCom` deletes currently.

For example using the TaskFlow API:

```py
    from airflow.models import XCom
    from airflow.utils.session import provide_session

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def push_xcom() -> dict:
        return {"xcom_1": "value_1", "xcom_2": "value_2"}

    @task
    @provide_session
    def delete_xcom(key: str, task_id: str, dag_id: str, session=None) -> None:
        session.query(XCom).filter(
            XCom.key==key, XCom.task_id==task_id, XCom.dag_id==dag_id
        ).delete()
        session.commit()

    push_xcom() >> delete_xcom(key="xcom_2", task_id="push_xcom", dag_id=dag.dag_id)
```

The "push_xcom" task will push two separate `XComs` -- *xcom_1* and *xcom_2*. (You can ignore the "return_value" `XCom` for this example as that particular `XCom` is created by default when a task has a return value.)
[image]

Querying the metastore DB confirms that all of the `XComs` have been stored.
[image]

The "delete_xcom" task will *only* delete the `XCom` with a key of "xcom_2". After successful run of that task, querying the metastore DB again shows that the `XCom` row for the "xcom_2" key has been deleted.
[image]

Finally, looking at the `XComs` returned from the "push_xcom" task in the UI, the `XCom` with a key of "xcom_2" is no longer visible either.
[image]